# Adding custom links like 'Like' / 'Share' / 'Comment' in newsfeed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

I just want to know if its possible to add a custom button like 'Like'/'Share'/'Comment' in Facebook's newsfeed.

I wanna add an action like 'Mark as unread' to Posts appearing on the user's newsfeed, so that the user can check them out later.

I found this browser add-on : http://socialfixer.com
So this enables certain functions on a user's newsfeed. I was wondering if this could be achieved through a Facebook app,  without the help of a browser add-on.

Thanks :)

Comment: You can post “actions” with your links, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I assume 'Posting' actions would mean, sharing/posting something via a third party application.

In my case, if the user grants permission to a facebook app, the 'action' should appear in all posts (from friends & pages) that the user sees, which would MARK a particular post. 

In short, I want an additional functionality to be enabled with all posts in the user's newsfeed. (Nothing is related to the user's post. Its a feature that has to appear with other user's posts). Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, didn’t understand that correctly before. No, a Facebook app does not let you manipulate what the user sees in their newsfeed – that would be a case for a browser extension.